# In dagster, how do I load_asset_value from a job executed in process with mem_io_manager?

Tags: python, dagster

For this question, consider I have a repository with one asset:

```py
@asset
def my_int():
    return 1

@repository
def my_repo():
    return [my_int]
```

I want to execute it in process (with mem_io_manager), but I would like to retrieve the value returned by my_int from memory later. I can do that with fs_io_manager, for example, using `my_repo.load_asset_value('my_int')`, after it ran. But the same method with mem_io_manager raises `dagster._core.errors.DagsterInvariantViolationError: Attempting to access step_key, but it was not provided when constructing the OutputContext`.

Ideally, I would execute it in process and tell the executor to return me one (or more) of the assets, something like:

```py
my_assets = my_repo.get_job('__ASSET_JOB').execute_in_process(return_assets=[my_int, ...])
```

Answer (score 2):

`mem_io_manager` doesn't store objects to file storage like `fs_io_manager`. You could in your `my_int` asset,

- save the value to a file or some other cloud storage and retrieve it later or
- Add the value as metadata if it is a simple integer or string and retrieve that later.

For the second case, using metadata, you can do:

```
@asset
def my_int(context):
    return Output(my_int_value, metadata={'my_int_value': my_int_value})
```

and to retrieve it later you could in another asset:

```
@asset
def retrieve_my_int(context):
     asset_key = 'my_int'
     latest_materialization_event = (
            self.init_context.instance.get_latest_materialization_events(
                [asset_key]
            ).get(asset_key)
        )
     if latest_materialization_event:
         materialization = (
                latest_materialization_event.dagster_event.event_specific_data.materialization
            )
         metadata = {
                entry.label: entry.entry_data
                for entry in materialization.metadata_entries
            }
         retrieved_int = metadata['my_int_value'].value if 'my_int_value' in metadata.keys() else None
      .......
```

the metadata approach has limitations, as you can only store certain kinds of data. If you want to store any kind of data, you'd have to execute the jobs differently so that the results can be materialized to a file system or an io_manager of choice.

You'd have to instead of `execute_in_process`, use `materialize`.

```
@asset
def my_int(context):
    ....


@asset
def asset_other(context):
    ....


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asset_results = materialize(
      load_assets_from_current_module()
    )
```

This will materialize the assets and you could specify which io_manager to use in the resource parameter. To retrieve an asset value, you can do

```
my_int_value = asset_results.output_for_node('my_int')
```

Comment: metadata has limitations about the data type it can handle right? It wouldn't work in my case, I need to return Any type of object. And I would not pass it to another asset, I would actually need to access it outside the run.

Comment: I specifically needed to execute_in_process with mem_io_manager, so the materialize would not fit. But you pointed me in the right direction, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear - do you want to materialize the asset in-process, then at a later time / in a different process access the result? Or do you just want to execute in process and get the result back?

In the former case, @Kay is correct that the result will disappear after the process completes as when using the `mem_io_manager` the memory the result is stored in is tied to the lifecycle of the process.

In the latter case, you should be able to do something like

```py
from dagster import materialize
asset_result = materialize([my_int])
```

Answer (score 0):

Both answers given so far would require the materialization (to disk), which is not what I wanted in the first place, I wanted to retrieve the value from memory.

But @kay pointed me in the right direction. `output_for_node` works on `execute_in_process` result, so that the following code achieves what I desired (retrieving `my_int` results from memory, after the jobs execution).

```py
from dagster import asset, repository

@asset
def my_int():
    return 1

@repository
def my_repo():
    return [my_int]

my_assets = my_repo.get_job('__ASSET_JOB').execute_in_process()
my_assets.output_for_node("my_int")
```